# Tableau: COUNTD using IF statement

Tags: tableau-api

I have a tableau data grid that I need to count distinct records. If the status is Complete distinct count the RecordID `IF [Status] = "COMPLETE" THEN COUNTD([Survey ID]) ELSE 0 END)`, but I am getting an error "Cannot mix aggregate and non-aggregate comparisons or results in IF expression". Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are close, but you need to rearrange the order of things.

```
COUNTD(IF [Status] = "COMPLETE" THEN [Survey ID] END)
```

This will return a `Survey ID` if the `Status` is 'COMPLETE' otherwise it will return a `NULL` to the `COUNTD` function. `NULL`s are ignored, so they won't be counted.

Comment: For the sake of clarity later on, it might help to explicitly state `ELSE NULL`

Comment: @Nicarus I'm a newbie and tableau.. and thanks for your help. :)